# How to track contribution from a mailout sent from civimail?

Tags: civimail, contributions, contribution-page, mailing, tracked-links

I am trying to see how many contribution has been generated as a result of  the recent mailout I sent from civimail.

What is the best approach to setup and track this please? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the nifty [Referral Source](https://civicrm.org/extensions/referral-source) extension. Here's how it works: https://civicrm.org/blog/stoob/new-ways-track-referral-source.

If you are wanting to use in combination with checksum build your URL e.g.

[https://example.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=IDNUMBER&source=AndyBurns&{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}](https://example.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=IDNUMBER&source=AndyBurns&%7Bcontact.checksum%7D&cid=%7Bcontact.contact_id%7D)

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy. Is it expected to work with checksum link as well?

Comment: Give it a try, I'd expect it would.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work at all, I'm on 5.38.2

Comment: I can confirm it works, Civi 5.35.2 but doubt that matters here. Updating my answer above.

Comment: Thanks I, have managed to get it working finally. There was a conflicting extension.

Comment: What extension?

Comment: It was one of my custom extensions, not publicly available.